# alternating row colours with 3 different background

Tags: php, css

Instead of 2 rows, which i am currently able to produce, I need a way to alternate between 3 colours for the table rows.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    tr.d0 td {
        background-color: #FFFFFF; color: black;

    }
    tr.d1 td {
        background-color: rgba(79, 129, 128, .2); color: black;

    }
    tr.d2 td {
        background-color: rgba(119, 149, 60, .2); color: black;

    }
    </style>

for($i =0; $i ...){

$rowclass = 0;
<tr class="d<?php echo $rowclass; ?>">

</tr>

$rowclass = 1 - $rowclass;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rowclass = (1 + $rowclass) % 3;
```

or even better, scrap that and just use

```
$i % 3
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just modified to this ($i+1) % 3. since the first 2 rows were both returning 0 as counter starts at 0.

Answer (score 3):

Not related to PHP, but, if you're using CSS3, it supports some [structural pseudo classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos). You could try using `:nth-of-type(3n), :nth-of-type(3n+1),:nth-of-type(3n+2)` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `modulo` operator. That's `%` in PHP (and most C-style languages), and it will get you the remainder of whatever number you're dividing by. In this case, you can use it to construct the className for each row like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $max, $i++) {
  $className = 'd' . ($i % 3);

  echo '<tr class="' . $className . '">';
  // do something with the row
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution not using PHP itself, but jQuery, could be as easy as:

```
$("table tr").each(function () {
    var i = $("table tr").index($(this));
    $(this).addClass("d" + (i % 3));
});
```

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvxaX/) to illustrate this scenario.